# Drupal 6 not loading page-user.tpl.php file

Tags: drupal-6, drupal-theming

I am running a Drupal 6 installation and am using domainname.com/user to use Drupal's special functionality (ie display the login screen if the user isn't login or display the user's profile if they are). The problem is that I have created a page-user.tpl.php file and have it placed in the template directory under the theme directory that I am using. In there is the page.tpl.php file as well so Drupal should find these template files. The problem that I have is that Drupal is not loading the page-user.tpl.php file but is loading the page.tpl.php file. I have cleared the cache numerous times but it is still not loading.

I have no idea what is wrong. Can someone please help me as I am pulling my hair out. I have googled for an answer but can't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

1. You said you cleared cache, but how did you do it? Are you sure you cleared theme registry cache? That can be done in one click if you use [admin_menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) module or if you go to some view -> `theme: information`.
2. To see what template files and functions are called, install [devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module. You would see the exact templates (and suggestions of templates for deeper themeing) there.